# advance search in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, search, project

I have these tables:

```
players
player_histories
clubs
```

I want to search in the `playerhistory`.
If we search for player name, then all the player details should be displayed.

In the player table:

```
        $table->string('name');
        $table->date('DOB');
        $table->string('permanent_address');
        $table->string('temporary_address');
        $table->string('blood_group');
        $table->float('height');
        $table->float('weight');
        $table->string('complexion');
        $table->bigInteger('contact_home');
```

In club table:

```
        $table->integer('club_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('club_id')->references('id')->on('clubs')->onDelete('cascade');         
        $table->integer('championship_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('championship_id')->references('id')->on('championship_details')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('game_result_status');
```

In playerhistories table

```
        $table->integer('player_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('player_id')->references('id')->on('players')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('previous_club_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('previous_club_id')->references('id')->on('clubs')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('current_club_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('current_club_id')->references('id')->on('clubs')->onDelete('cascade');           
        $table->float('salary');
```

My process:
routes.blade.php

```
Route::post(
'search/player',
array(
    'as' => 'search/player',
    'uses' => 'PlayerHistoryController@searchPlayer'
)
```

);

View Page

```
 {!! Form::open(array('method' => 'Post', 'url' => 'search/player')) !!}
                         <div class="col-md-3">
                         </div>
                           <div class="col-md-3">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="search_text">Search Text</label>
                                    {!! Form::text('search_text',null,array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Search player')) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">

                        {!! form::submit('Search Player',[' class'=>'btn btn-primary form-control'])!!}


                        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Controller:

```
public function searchPlayer(PlayerHistory $playerhistories, CreateArticleRequest $request) {

    $search_text = $request->input ( 'search_text' );


    $playerhistories = $playerhistories->searchByPlayer($search_text);

    return view('pages.searchPlayer', compact('playerhistories'));
}
```

repository:

```
 public function searchByPlayer(){
     $first = $this->makeModel()->where('player_id', "LIKE", '%' . $search_text . '%')->where('permanent_address', "LIKE", '%' . $search_text . '%');
}
```

I want to put a name in `player_id`. How is it possible? Do we have to use `union` to search every field entered in 1 search text?

Thank you in advance.